# Button doesn't change bg image from an ID element inside of a <style> element (PHP, JS, HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, html

Im not good at programming in PHP and JS, but im trying to make a button that changes the background image from an ID element that is inside of a incorporated style element using this code:

My PHP/HTML code and button:

```
 <?php 
    $old-img-url = 'old-image.png';
    $new-img-url = 'new-image.png';
 ?>
 
 <style> #my-div-id *{ background-image: url('<?php echo $old-img-url ?>'); } </style>

 <div id='my-div-id'>
  // my extra code...
 </div>

 <?php
    echo "<button onclick='changeImage()'>Change image</button>";
 ?>
```

My script (out of the PHP code):

```
 <script>
 function changeImage() {
    const Imagechange = document.querySelector('#my-div-id');
    Imagechange.style.backgroundImage = "url('<?php echo $new-img-url ?>')";
 }
 </script>
```

Welp, my problem is that the button works and loads the url of the new background image for the ID, but it doesn't replace it. It appears like this:

[image: Error screenshot]

It's there any way to fix this? And if not, is there an alternative for give a solution to this? Thanks and cheers.

Note: I tried quitting some PHP line codes to convert then in HTML elements, because i know that PHP renders all the elements written inside of it into the page and doesn't allows you to do more changes when it is rendered, so then, i tried to do that to see if there was a difference, but there wasn't. So it stills with the same problem.

Comment: Unless you write both variables to the markup, you can't change them through JS. Also, `$old-image-url` is not a valid variable name, as it should not contain dashes

Comment: Finally, what do you mean by "Error screenshot"? Please share more details about that error, which I cannot find in that screenshot

Comment: Hello. The screenshot is inside the text that says that, just click it and it will appear. About your other comments, i will take a look at that. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't share neccessary details hidden in a screenshot

Comment: First time in the forum, sorry about that. Thank for share your post, now i understand that Javascript can't change nothing after the website gets rendered by PHP. So i fixed it using forms. Cheers.

Comment: Javascript can change a lot of stuff after PHP rendered the code, that's the point in using JS